# Syzygy tablebases in xboard

Tags: stockfish, tablebases, uci, winboard

I'm trying to set up the five-men syzygy tablebases for use in xboard 4.8. Stockfish 6 and Komodo 9 are both supposed to support Syzygy, but in Xboard, their SyzygyPath option is missing from the UCI options.

I've tried setting up the tablebase through the GUI options but there's no documentation on how to do this with Syzygy rather than Nalimov that I can find. Anyone have a clue how this is done?

Comment: Are you using Polyglot? My answer will depend on whether you're using it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, actually. I don't think I ever installed it. How would I go about checking?

Answer (score 3):

xboard is not a UCI user interface, so you'll need to install the Polyglot adapter to make it work. Once you have the Polyglot installed, you'll need to edit the polyglot.ini file. Read [here](http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?t=49621) for instructions on how to do it.

Please note Polyglot is not a very professionally made software. You'll only be able to find some old documentation. The whole process is quite technical. If you don't want to spend the time, you might as well consider other user-interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the path with "syzygy:" (without quotes), at least, if there is only one path and you don't care about any other table type.